# IBM MFP 8 Push Notification Rest API Examples

Tags: push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

Need sample App for Push Notification using ONLY REST Api service. Please share the link.

Answer (score 0):

The sample applications available use the IBM MobileFirst Push SDK, which automatically invoke the MFP Push REST endpoints.
There are no samples available that invoke MFP Push endpoints directly without SDK.

All the MFP Push REST endpoints are published [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/rest_runtime/c_restapi_runtime.html).

You will have to create your own sample that invokes the REST endpoints. You can capture and analyze the network traffic between MFP Push SDK and Push service to understand the sequence of events.